# Parse Server one-to-one relationship, to store different pointer

Tags: javascript, typescript, parse-platform

I design Event Model of my server, which contains a lot of events related to many users. For example (since I use javascript SDK, let me describe the structure with Typescript):

```
interface IEventBase {
   user: Parse.User;
}
interface IEventStartWork extends IEventBase {
   late: boolean;
}
interface IEventAfterWork extends IEventBase {
   jobDone: boolean;
}
interface IEventDrinkWaters extends IEventBase {
   howManyTimes: number;
}
interface IEventGoOutForLunch extends IEventBase {
   howLong: number;
}
```

In my case, I have more than 100 different kind of events, and I need to take all events happened to one user as fast as possible. **And I cannot put them into one single collection, because I have to add index on each event when necessary.** So I attempt to put them into one indexed, collection with pointer:

```
interface IEvents {
    user: Parse.User;
    pointer: IEventBase;
}
```

By this design I can quickly pull out all events of an user, in any time range.

But then I got error when storing different events into `Events` collection, showing error:

```
schema mismatch for Events.entity; expected Pointer<EventStartWork> but got Pointer<EventAfterWork>
```

What can I do to achieve this goal with Parse Server, maybe disable schema checking on single field?